# The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established passing "yes" with a bash script

Tags: bash, git, unix, github, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a personal project that requires me to do some bash scripting. I am currently trying to write a script that pulls from my private git repo. At the moment I am able to spin up my instance and install all my packages through a script. But when it comes to pulling from my private repo I get `The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established`

I am trying to figure out a way to pass "yes" with my script. I know this is very bad practice but for my current use case, I'm not too concerned about security.

running this `ssh-keyscan github.com >>~/.ssh/known_hosts` command manual works, but when I put this in my script it does not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
My script:

```
echo "update install -start"
sudo yum -y update
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
sudo yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
sudo yum install -y git
sudo systemctl start httpd
echo "end"
#file premissions
sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www && find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
#pulling from my git repo
ssh-keyscan github.com >>~/.ssh/known_hosts
cd ../../var/www/html/
git clone git@github.com:jackbourkemckenna/testrepo
```

Comment: Add your script to your question.

Comment: Apologies added it there.